# Riverpod state update does not rebuild the widget

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm using **StateProvider<List<String>>** to keep track of user taps on the Tic Tac Toe board.
Actual board is a widget that extends **ConsumerWidget** and consists of tap-able GridView.

Within the **onTap** event of GridViews child - following is invoked to update the state:

```
ref.read(gameBoardStateProvider.notifier).state[index] = 'X';
```

**For some reason this does not invoke widget rebuild event**. Due to this I cannot see the 'X' in the GridView item which was tapped.

However, if I add additional "simple" StateProvider<int> and invoke it as well within the same onTap event then the widget gets rebuilt and I can see the 'X' in the GridView.
I am not even using or displaying this additional state provider but for some reason it invokes rebuild while my intended provided doesn't.

```
final gameBoardStateProvider = StateProvider<List<String>>((ref) => List.filled(9, '', growable: false));

final testStateProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0); //dummy state provider

class Board extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Board({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final gameBoard = ref.watch(gameBoardStateProvider);
    final testState = ref.watch(testStateProvider);

    return Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 9,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: ((BuildContext context, int index) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                //With this line only the widget does not get refreshed - and I do not see board refreshed with added 'X'
                ref.read(gameBoardStateProvider.notifier).state[index] = 'X';
                //??? If I add this line as well - for some reason the widget get refreshed - and I see board refreshed with added 'X'
                ref.read(testStateProvider.notifier).state++;
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(gameBoard[index]),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you do

```dart
ref.read(gameBoardStateProvider.notifier).state[index] = 'X'
```

Means changing a single variable. In order to update the UI, you need to provide a new list as State.

You can do it like

```dart
List<String> oldState = ref.read(gameBoardStateProvider);
oldState[index] = "X";
ref
    .read(gameBoardStateProvider.notifier)
    .update((state) => oldState.toList());
```

Or

```dart
List<String> oldState = ref.read(gameBoardStateProvider);
oldState[index] = "X";
ref.read(gameBoardStateProvider.notifier).state =
    oldState.toList();
```

**Why `testStateProvider` works:**

Because it contains single int as State where `gameBoardStateProvider` contains `List<String>` as State.

> Just updating single variable doesn't refresh ui on `state_provider`, You need to update the state to force a refresh

More about [`state_provider`](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_provider/)

You can also check [`change_notifier_provider`](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/change_notifier_provider/)

Comment: Thank you! I learned from something new :) I expected that by updating the value of the list I am actually changing the list and that this means state change - but it's not the case

Answer (score 4):

The reason the ""simple"" `StateProvider` triggers a rebuild and your *actual* doesn't is because you aren't reassigning its value.

`StateProvider`s works like this:

1. `StateProvider` is just a `StateNotifierProvider` that uses a simple implementation of a `StateNotifier` that exposes its `get state` and `set state` methods (and an additional `update` method);
2. `StateNotifier` works like this: an *actual* state update consists of a **reassignment**. Whenever `state` gets **reassigned** it triggers its listeners (just like `ChangeNotifier` would do). See immutability patterns.

This means that, since you're exposing a `List<String>`, doing something like `state[0] = "my new string` **will NOT** trigger rebuilds. Only actions such as `state = [... anotherList];` will do.

This is desirable, since `StateNotifier` pushes you to use immutable data, which is can be good pattern in the frontend world.

Instead, your `int StateProvider` will basically always trigger an update, since chances are that when you need to alter its state, *you need to reassign its value*.

For your use case you can do something like:

```dart
state[i] = 'x';
state = [...state];
```

This forces a re-assignment, and as such it will trigger the update.

**Note**: since you're implementing a tic-tac-toe, it is maybe desirable to handle mutable data for that grid. Try using a `ChangeNotifier`, implement some update logic (with `notifiyListeners()`) and exposing it with a `ChangeNotifierProvider`.

Riverpod actually advises *against* mutable patterns (i.e. against `ChangeNotifier`s), but, as there is no silver bullet in Computer Science, your use case might be different.

Comment: Thank you. I've checked StateNotifierProvider docs and I see that its recommended approach for user interaction related state updates and more complex state data. I'll add in my answer below the implementation. Although it seems like an overkill compared to just using StateProvider. Probably it will make more sense once I start introducing more complex business logic...

Comment: You're most welcome! Again, by seeing your use case I'd use a `ChangeNotifier` and manipulate the mutable list. The author of Riverpod generally advises to use `StateNotifier` instead, but as there's no silver bullet in computer science, your case fits the usage of a `ChangeNotifier`, better.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to both *Yeasin* and *venir* for clarifying what it means to reassign the state and the difference between simple and complex types.

While keeping the initial StateProvider I've replaced

```
ref.read(gameBoardStateProvider.notifier).state[index] = 'X';
```

with

```
var dataList = ref.read(gameBoardStateProvider);
dataList[index] = 'X';
ref.read(gameBoardStateProvider.notifier).state = [...dataList];
```

And it works now - the state gets updated and the widget rebuilt.

I've also tried the StateNotifier approach and it also works - although it seems more convoluted to me :) I'm pasting the code bellow as it can maybe benefit someone else to see the example.

```
class GameBoardNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<String>> {
  GameBoardNotifier() : super(List.filled(9, '', growable: false));

  void updateBoardItem(String player, int index) {
    state[index] = player;
    state = [...state];
  }
}

final gameBoardProvider = StateNotifierProvider<GameBoardNotifier, List<String>>((ref) => GameBoardNotifier());

class Board extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Board({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final gameBoard = ref.watch(gameBoardProvider);

    return Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 9,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: ((BuildContext context, int index) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                ref.read(gameBoardProvider.notifier).updateBoardItem('X', index);
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(gameBoard[index]),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```